# According to the YEC view, did the animals eat the forbidden fruit?

Tags: sin, genesis, adam-and-eve, young-earth-creation, animals

Assuming the Young Earth Creationist view that the Genesis account is literal history...

When Adam and Eve ate the forbidden fruit they were condemned to death which caused every subsequent human to bear death's potential. The question is: since animals also die just like each and every one of us, did they also eat the forbidden fruit?

Answer (score 8):

Most adherents to the literal young-earth seven-day creation account believe that when Adam and Eve ate of the fruit, God applied the curse to the entire universe, including animals.  Animals didn't need to eat the fruit to be affected by the curse. From the YEC view, whether animals ate the fruit is irrelevant because they weren't made "in God's image"

Supporting example, from http://www.answersingenesis.org/articles/kw/museum-guide-corruption

> God had warned Adam and Eve that if they ate of the Tree, they would
>   die. When God came to walk with them that evening, He punished their
>   sin. The earth was now cursed. Death was now part of life; both
>   animals and humans would now die (Genesis 3:19; Romans 8:20–22). When
>   the first humans sinned, it corrupted all of creation. The ground was
>   cursed and would produce thistles and thorns (Genesis 3:17–18).
>   Animals began to hunt and eat other animals. Man would now have to
>   work hard for food, and woman would have pain in bearing and raising
>   her children (Genesis 3:16–17).

[The Institute for Creation Research (ICR)](http://www.icr.org/article/837/) says this:

> The animals, not having moral natures, were not guilty of sin, of
>   course, but they also shared in the Curse, for they were—like
>   Adam—made of the dust of the ground that God had cursed. Like Adam's
>   body, their bodies also must return to the ground. Henceforth, "death
>   reigned ... even over them that had not sinned after the similitude of
>   Adam's transgression" (Romans 5:14). Thus there is death in the world
>   only because there is sin in the world.

Comment: The question is, *"Did the animals eat the forbidden fruit?"* - I don't think you've answered that.

Comment: @wikis  Good point. I did address the question in the body, which was "since animals also die, does this mean they ate the fruit ?" but not explicitly. I edited to be more clear on that, but still this answers the question in the body of the question rather than the title.